# whats the difference between DocumentRoot and Directory

Tags: apache2

Plaese till me what is the difference between DocumentRoot and Directory in default file
default file in apache2 has three blocks

```
DocumentRoot /var/www   in me server /sda1/htdocs

<Directory />
    Options FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride None
</Directory>

<Directory /var/www>   in my server sda1/htdocs>
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
    AllowOverride None
    Order allow,deny
    allow from all
</Directory>
```

May I use just these two in sda1/htdocs directory

```
DocumentRoot /sda1/htdocs

<Directory /sda1/htdocs>
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
    AllowOverride None
    Order allow,deny
    allow from all
</Directory>
```

With many Thanks

Answer (score 4):

Here's an excerpt from the official [Apache documentation](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/core.html#directory):

> If multiple (non-regular expression) Directory sections match the
>   directory (or one of its parents) containing a document, then the
>   directives are applied in the order of shortest match first,
>   interspersed with the directives from the .htaccess files. For
>   example, with
>
> ```
> <Directory /> AllowOverride None </Directory>
>
> <Directory /home> AllowOverride FileInfo </Directory>
> ```
>
> for access to the document /home/web/dir/doc.html the steps are:
>
> ```
> Apply directive AllowOverride None (disabling .htaccess files).
> Apply directive AllowOverride FileInfo (for directory /home).
> Apply any FileInfo directives in /home/.htaccess, /home/web/.htaccess and /home/web/dir/.htaccess in that order.
> ```

I.e. `Directory /` directive defines "defaults" for all other directories, which can be overridden by each particular directory

In your case both of the versions you're showing should be equivalent unless you have other Directory directives.